# Why is my code not compiling

Tags: python, praw

I am just learning Python and decided to write a really simple Python bot to reply on Reddit.

On compiling I am getting the following error:

> File "C:\Python35\Scripts\RedditBot\Reddit.py", line 28
>       except attributeerror:
>            ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I am unable to see what is causing this as the code looks correct to me.

```
import praw

USERAGENT = "BOT Name"
USERNAME = "Username"
PASSWORD = "Password"
SUBREDDIT = "Subreddit"
MAXPOSTS = 100

SETPHRASES = ["Phrase", "PhraseOne"]
SETRESPONSE = "This is the response."

print('Logging in to Reddit')
r = praw.Reddit(USERAGENT)
r.login (USERNAME, PASSWORD)

def replybot():
    print('Fetching Subreddit ' + SUBREDDIT)
    subreddit = r.get_subreddit(SUBREDDIT)
    print('Fetching comments')
    comments = subreddit.get_comments(limit=MAXPOSTS)
    for comment in comments:
        try:
            cauthor = comment.author.name
            cbody = comment.body.lower()
            if any(key.lower() in cbody for key in SETPHRASES):
                print("Replying to " + cauthor)
                comment.reply(SETRESPONSE)
            except attributeerror:
                pass
replybot()
```

Comment: except's indent is wrong

Comment: Also looks like `attributeerror` should be `AttributeError` to avoid another problem.

Comment: And it looks like you put your own scripts in the Python installation folder. Don't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having two problems.

- First one, which is displayed in traceback, is the indentation. "try"
  and "except" must be on the same level of indentation.
- Second one is the reference to attributeerror. It need's to be camelcased as in AttributeError.

So the inside of your for loop should look as follows:

```
try:
   cauthor = comment.author.name
   cbody = comment.body.lower()
   if any(key.lower() in cbody for key in SETPHRASES):
      print("Replying to " + cauthor)
      comment.reply(SETRESPONSE)
except AttributeError:
   pass
```

Comment: Thanks. I will be more careful with my cases and indentation going forward.